# How to style each individual drop down menu and put in table using xsl and php

Tags: php, html, css, xml, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm trying to select a value from a drop-down menu, and display the information from XML into a table. When i tried it in PHP to load the styling, it displays the selected option in text and then everything in a table.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showBus(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getbus.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>Select your bus route:
            <select name="NUMBER" onchange="showBus(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select a Bus:</option>
                <option value="102">102</option>
            </select>
            <div id="txtHint"><b>Bus info will be listed here...</b>
            </div>
        </form>
```

```php
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("routes.xml");
    $x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $x->length - 1; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($x->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
                $y = ($x->item($i)->parentNode);
            }
        }
    }

    $BUS = ($y->childNodes);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $BUS->length; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($BUS->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            echo("<b>" . $BUS->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
            echo($BUS->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
            echo("<br>");
        }
    }
?>
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="routes.xsl"?>

<TT>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>102</NUMBER>    
<DEPARTING_STOP>Sutton</DEPARTING_STOP>
<DESTINATION>Airport</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00</TIME>
<TIME>07:00</TIME>
<TIME>08:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:30</TIME>
</BUS>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>15</NUMBER>    
<DEPARTING_STOP>Clongriffin</DEPARTING_STOP>
<DESTINATION>Ballyycullen road</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00</TIME>
<TIME>07:00</TIME>
<TIME>08:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:30</TIME>
</BUS>

</TT>
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what is not working? Any errors?

Comment: No errors. I'm just looking to select a bus number from a dropdown menu, and then display the buses information so number, time stop ect in a table

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is no code review service but Q&A for specific problems. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic